# If loop in jquery while appending html

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, if-statement

This code works:

```
$("<h2/>")
.html("oSingle.hooks.m4a")
.appendTo(contentdiv);
```

But I need to check if there is a value (if there isn't "undefined" gets displayed), if it's empty/undefined I don't need to display anything, so I tried:

```
$("<p/>")
if(oSingle.hooks.m4a == "undefined")
{
    .html("")//do nothing
}else{
    .html(oSingle.hooks.m4a)
    .appendTo(contentdiv);
}
```

But this isn't working, can someone please tell me how to correctly create an if loop?

Comment: whatever you tried that is having several syntax errors....

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about syntax issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is syntactically incorrect, you can just do

```
if (oSingle.hooks.m4a != "undefined") {
    $("<p/>").html(oSingle.hooks.m4a).appendTo(contentdiv);
}
```

But I suspect what you really may want to do is

```
if (oSingle && oSingle.hooks && oSingle.hooks.m4a != undefined) {
    $("<p/>").html(oSingle.hooks.m4a).appendTo(contentdiv);
}
```

Comment: using `typeOf` will return a string `"undefined"`  Am I right.?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy yes it will.... still may have to check whether `oSingle.hooks` exists